# Aggregate data by groups with missing data values

Tags: r, grouping, aggregate, na

I have a data with NA like this,

```
   D1   pobox HID S1 locID UID C1  C2 C3 C4 C5 C6
1   1 Box 134   2  1    -9   4 NA  NA NA NA NA NA
2   1 Box 134   2  1     2   4  3  99 10 10  0  0
3   1  Box 35   3 NA    NA   2 NA  NA NA NA NA NA
4   1 Box 169   7 NA    NA   3 NA  NA NA NA NA NA
5   2 Box 115  12  2    -9   4 NA  NA NA NA NA NA
6   2 Box 115  12  2     2   4  0   7 90 10 NA  0
7   2 Box 126  16  3    -9   3  0   0  0  0  0  0
8   3  Box 72  17 NA    NA   4 NA  NA NA NA NA NA
9   3  Box 54  19  4    -9   4  0   0  0  0  0  0
10  3  Box 71  22 NA    NA   2 NA  NA NA NA NA NA
11  4  Box 61  23  5    -9   4 NA  NA NA NA NA NA
12  4  Box 61  23  5     2   4  0 100  0 NA  0  0
13  4  Box 61  23  5    12   4  0  15  0 10 NA  0        
14  4   Box 4  27  6    -9   4  0   0  0  0  0  0
15  4  Box 64  29 NA    NA   3 NA  NA NA NA NA NA
16  4 Box 144  30 NA    NA   2 NA  NA NA NA NA NA
```

I want to do aggregate (Say,sum) C1,C2,C3,C4,C5,C6 by D1,pobox,HID,S1,UID
What I want to get is a data like this, ignoring NA when at least one entry has number, and keep NA when all entries are NA.

```
   D1   pobox HID S1 UID V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6
1   1 Box 134   2  1   4  3 99 10 10  0  0
2   1  Box 35   3 NA   2 NA NA NA NA NA NA
3   1 Box 169   7 NA   3 NA NA NA NA NA NA
4   2 Box 115  12  2   4  0  7 90 10 NA  0
5   2 Box 126  16  3   3  0  0  0  0  0  0
6   3  Box 72  17 NA   4 NA NA NA NA NA NA
7   3  Box 54  19  4   4  0  0  0  0  0  0
8   3  Box 71  22 NA   2 NA NA NA NA NA NA
9   4  Box 61  23  5   4  0 115 0 10  0  0
10  4   Box 4  27  6   4  0  0  0  0  0  0
11  4  Box 64  29 NA   3 NA NA NA NA NA NA
12  4 Box 144  30 NA   2 NA NA NA NA NA NA
```

I tried

> aggregate(cbind(C1,C2,C3,C4,C5,C6) ~ D1+pobox+HID+S1+UID, data = test, sum, na.action=na.pass, na.rm=TRUE)

```
  D1   pobox HID S1 UID C1  C2 C3 C4 C5 C6
1  2 Box 126  16  3   3  0   0  0  0  0  0
2  1 Box 134   2  1   4  3  99 10 10  0  0
3  2 Box 115  12  2   4  0   7 90 10  0  0
4  3  Box 54  19  4   4  0   0  0  0  0  0
5  4  Box 61  23  5   4  0 115  0 10  0  0
6  4   Box 4  27  6   4  0   0  0  0  0  0
```

This did not work,
Next, I tried summaryBy with doBy package

> summaryBy(C1+C2+C3+C4+C5 ~ D1+pobox+HID+S1+UID, FUN=sum, data = test, na.rm=TRUE, na.pass=TRUE, keep.names=TRUE)

This resulted all NA got 1

```
   D1   pobox HID S1 UID C1  C2 C3 C4 C5
1   1 Box 134   2  1   4  4 100 11 11  1
2   1 Box 169   7 NA   3  1   1  1  1  1
3   1  Box 35   3 NA   2  1   1  1  1  1
4   2 Box 115  12  2   4  1   8 91 11  1
5   2 Box 126  16  3   3  1   1  1  1  1
6   3  Box 54  19  4   4  1   1  1  1  1
7   3  Box 71  22 NA   2  1   1  1  1  1
8   3  Box 72  17 NA   4  1   1  1  1  1
9   4 Box 144  30 NA   2  1   1  1  1  1
10  4   Box 4  27  6   4  1   1  1  1  1
11  4  Box 61  23  5   4  1 116  1 11  1
12  4  Box 64  29 NA   3  1   1  1  1  1
```

Tried data.table package

> sumt<-DT[,list(sum(C1),sum(C2),sum(C3),sum(C4),sum(C5),sum(C6)),by=list(D1,pobox,HID,S1,UID)]

```
   D1   pobox HID S1 UID V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6
1   1 Box 134   2  1   4 NA NA NA NA NA NA
2   1  Box 35   3 NA   2 NA NA NA NA NA NA
3   1 Box 169   7 NA   3 NA NA NA NA NA NA
4   2 Box 115  12  2   4 NA NA NA NA NA NA
5   2 Box 126  16  3   3  0  0  0  0  0  0
6   3  Box 72  17 NA   4 NA NA NA NA NA NA
7   3  Box 54  19  4   4  0  0  0  0  0  0
8   3  Box 71  22 NA   2 NA NA NA NA NA NA
9   4  Box 61  23  5   4 NA NA NA NA NA NA
10  4   Box 4  27  6   4  0  0  0  0  0  0 
11  4  Box 64  29 NA   3 NA NA NA NA NA NA
12  4 Box 144  30 NA   2 NA NA NA NA NA NA
```

Now, with na.rm=TRUE,

> sumt<-DT[,list(sum(C1,na.rm=TRUE),sum(C2,na.rm=TRUE),sum(C3,na.rm=TRUE),sum(C4,na.rm=TRUE),sum(C5,na.rm=TRUE),sum(C6,na.rm=TRUE)),by=list(D1,pobox,HID,S1,UID)]

```
   D1   pobox HID S1 UID V1  V2 V3 V4 V5 V6
1   1 Box 134   2  1   4  3  99 10 10  0  0
2   1  Box 35   3 NA   2  0   0  0  0  0  0
3   1 Box 169   7 NA   3  0   0  0  0  0  0
4   2 Box 115  12  2   4  0   7 90 10  0  0
5   2 Box 126  16  3   3  0   0  0  0  0  0
6   3  Box 72  17 NA   4  0   0  0  0  0  0
7   3  Box 54  19  4   4  0   0  0  0  0  0
8   3  Box 71  22 NA   2  0   0  0  0  0  0
9   4  Box 61  23  5   4  0 115  0 10  0  0
10  4   Box 4  27  6   4  0   0  0  0  0  0
11  4  Box 64  29 NA   3  0   0  0  0  0  0
12  4 Box 144  30 NA   2  0   0  0  0  0  0
```

Comment: You say you want to "keep NA when all entries are NA", but actually none of your columns C1-C6 have all entries as NA.

Comment: @arvi1000, not in all rows but all rows of a group

Answer (score 3):

Here's a dplyr option:

```
library(dplyr)
test %>% 
  group_by(D1,pobox,HID,S1,UID) %>% 
  summarise_each(funs(
       if(all(is.na(.))) NA else sum(., na.rm = TRUE)), 
       num_range("C", 1:6))       # could add %>% ungroup() if necessary

#Source: local data frame [12 x 11]
#Groups: D1, pobox, HID, S1
#
#   D1   pobox HID S1 UID C1  C2 C3 C4 C5 C6
#1   1 Box 134   2  1   4  3  99 10 10  0  0
#2   1 Box 169   7 NA   3 NA  NA NA NA NA NA
#3   1  Box 35   3 NA   2 NA  NA NA NA NA NA
#4   2 Box 115  12  2   4  0   7 90 10 NA  0
#5   2 Box 126  16  3   3  0   0  0  0  0  0
#6   3  Box 54  19  4   4  0   0  0  0  0  0
#7   3  Box 71  22 NA   2 NA  NA NA NA NA NA
#8   3  Box 72  17 NA   4 NA  NA NA NA NA NA
#9   4 Box 144  30 NA   2 NA  NA NA NA NA NA
#10  4   Box 4  27  6   4  0   0  0  0  0  0
#11  4  Box 61  23  5   4  0 115  0 10  0  0
#12  4  Box 64  29 NA   3 NA  NA NA NA NA NA
```

---

Here's a little modification of the code above:

```
test %>% 
    group_by(D1,pobox,HID,S1,UID) %>% 
    summarise_each(funs(sum(., na.rm = !all(is.na(.)))), num_range("C", 1:6))
```

This way you can define the `na.rm =` parameter depending on the values in each group (it is TRUE if *not* all values are NA and FALSE otherwise).

---

And here's a similar data.table approach:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(test)[,lapply(.SD, function(x) sum(x, na.rm = !all(is.na(x)))), 
             .SDcols = paste0("C", 1:6), by = .(D1,pobox,HID,S1,UID)]
 #   D1   pobox HID S1 UID C1  C2 C3 C4 C5 C6
 #1:  1 Box 134   2  1   4  3  99 10 10  0  0
 #2:  1  Box 35   3 NA   2 NA  NA NA NA NA NA
 #3:  1 Box 169   7 NA   3 NA  NA NA NA NA NA
 #4:  2 Box 115  12  2   4  0   7 90 10 NA  0
 #5:  2 Box 126  16  3   3  0   0  0  0  0  0
 #6:  3  Box 72  17 NA   4 NA  NA NA NA NA NA
 #7:  3  Box 54  19  4   4  0   0  0  0  0  0
 #8:  3  Box 71  22 NA   2 NA  NA NA NA NA NA
 #9:  4  Box 61  23  5   4  0 115  0 10  0  0
#10:  4   Box 4  27  6   4  0   0  0  0  0  0
#11:  4  Box 64  29 NA   3 NA  NA NA NA NA NA
#12:  4 Box 144  30 NA   2 NA  NA NA NA NA NA
```

Comment: I also noticed that and was surprised

Comment: That's a nice `data.table` idea. I don't think you need the `.SDcols` part though.

Comment: Thanks (it was a nice dplyr idea first, actually). I guess the .SDcols part is necessary here - there's for example another non-grouping column "locid"

Comment: Oh, I didn't notice that column. So you probably could simplify to just `.SDcols = -"locID"` than.

Comment: I know I _could_ do that but I chose to do it the other way because we don't know if the OP has other columns in their real data and in such a case -locID would be wrong

Comment: Thanks all.  seems the key is writing a special sum function.  I didn't think about it.

Answer (score 0):

This is a solution using the `plyr`package

```
# recreate Data (need to wrap pobox in "s)
# use clipboard on Windows
data <- read.table(pipe("pbpaste"),header = T,stringsAsFactors = T)

library(plyr)  

# create conditional sum function
sum_rmna <- function(x) {
  if(all(is.na(x))){r <- sum(x)}
  if(!(all(is.na(x)))){r <- sum(x,na.rm = TRUE)}
return(r)}

# use ddply from plyr package
cdata <- ddply(data,c("D1","pobox","HID","S1"),summarise,
               V1 = sum_rmna(C1),
               V2 = sum_rmna(C2),
               V3 = sum_rmna(C3),
               V4 = sum_rmna(C4),
               V5 = sum_rmna(C5),
               V6 = sum_rmna(C6))
```

This will return

```
> cdata
   D1   pobox HID S1 V1  V2 V3 V4 V5 V6
1   1 Box 134   2  1  3  99 10 10  0  0
2   1 Box 169   7 NA NA  NA NA NA NA NA
3   1  Box 35   3 NA NA  NA NA NA NA NA
4   2 Box 115  12  2  0   7 90 10 NA  0
5   2 Box 126  16  3  0   0  0  0  0  0
6   3  Box 54  19  4  0   0  0  0  0  0
7   3  Box 71  22 NA NA  NA NA NA NA NA
8   3  Box 72  17 NA NA  NA NA NA NA NA
9   4 Box 144  30 NA NA  NA NA NA NA NA
10  4   Box 4  27  6  0   0  0  0  0  0
11  4  Box 61  23  5  0 115  0 10  0  0
12  4  Box 64  29 NA NA  NA NA NA NA NA
```